# Getting MAC address on VxWorks 6.8

Tags: c, networking, microcontroller, mac-address, vxworks

I'm trying to solve [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250949/how-to-generate-a-unique-id-on-vxworks-6-8), but i'm stuck getting ***MAC addresses*** on ***VxWorks 6.8***.

With `muxIoctl()` i don't get a correct result:

```
/* Binding the cookie */
PROTO_COOKIE muxCookie = muxBind( ... ); /* Binding network service <-> end */

/*
 * Error handling etc.
 * [...]
 */

/* Getting the the address */
char result[6];
STATUS status = muxIoctl(muxCookie, EIOCGADDR, result); /* ioctl the device address */

if( status != OK )
{
    /* Error handling */
}
else
{
    /* ioctl() was Ok, print 'result' */
}
```

What looks good to me fails in reality. As a result of `muxIoctl()`, the buffer doesn't contain the proper MAC-addres, instead it looks something like this (tested on two devices):

```
 Device #1: 00 00 00 00 0A 00
 Device #2: 00 00 00 00 0B 00
                        ^
                        |
 Every byte is 0, with the exception of these
```

Both devices have a valid MAC address, this can be seen by either `ifconfig` or at transmitted packets. Interfaces (as bound above) are fine and working.

Getting the cookie through `muxDevAcquire()` (or *deprcated* `endFindByName()`) instead of using the one of `muxBind()` directly has the same result.

In addition: `muxDevExists()` returns `TRUE` and another *"hacky"* code doesn't work as well (however it returns the values as above):

```
const char* devName = ...
int unit = ...

char result[6];
END_OBJ* end = endFindByName(devName, unit);

STATUS status = end->pFuncTable->ioctl(end, EIOCGADDR, result);
```

Btw. other controls over `muxIoctl()` at the same location work just fine.

The devices stated above use *dtsec* that's also working fine, with one exception: The *relevant case* of `dtsecEndIoctl()` - the underlying `ioctl()` to wich `muxIoctl()` delegates - doesn't set the address! It does *only once at system boot* (else it copies the bytes above)!

Since `EIOCGADDR`  of `dtsecEndIoctl()` does not much more than a `bcopy()` from `pDrvCtrl->dtsecAddr` (`pDrvCtrl` = `muxCookie` casted to `DTSEC_DRV_CTRL*`!?) it looks like a problem of the `muxCookie` to me. However the cookie is working fine every time and everywhere - expected here (side note: not tested on *etsec* yet).

**Long explanation, short question:** How to fix this, respectively how to get the MAC addrress?

---

**Other discussions addressing this issue:**

- http://compgroups.net/comp.os.vxworks/read-mac-address-on-vxworks-6.8/1115852
- https://groups.google.com/forum/?_escaped_fragment_=topic/comp.os.vxworks/djh_jH1I0Uk#!topic/comp.os.vxworks/djh_jH1I0Uk

*(All not working)*

---

**[Update]:** On *etsec* `muxIoctl()` uses the correct MAC, on *dtsec* wit fails as above.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like dtsecEndIoctl does not work properly.
In your END driver, end->pFuncTable->ioctl has address of dtsecEndIoctl.
It means that if `EIOCGADDR` of dtsecEndIoctl copies MAC correctly, end->pFuncTable->ioctl copies MAC correctly.